# Why does "netsh interface delete interface" doesn't work?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, home-networking, netsh

**Scenario**: Windows XP Professional SP3 (Hyper-V VM)

I'm trying to delete a specific network interface from my computer.

First of all, i showed all interfaces using the `netsh interface show interface` command:

[image]

Then, I decided to delete any of the "Local Area Connection" interfaces, from 1 to 7, but in all tries i got the same message: "The parameter is incorrect"

The syntax is exactly as in the example.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running the command with Admin privileges?

Comment: @DavidPostill Affirmative.

Answer (score 0):

As we learned from Conker, somethings in life are [context sensitive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cD91lWlqmNE).  Each level of commands in `netsh` has specific options available to it.  If you run `netsh ?` you will see that `delete` is listed under "Commands in this context":

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh ?

Usage: netsh [-a AliasFile] [-c Context] [-r RemoteMachine] [-u [DomainName\]UserName] [-p Password | *]
             [Command | -f ScriptFile]

The following commands are available:

Commands in this context:
?              - Displays a list of commands.
add            - Adds a configuration entry to a list of entries.
advfirewall    - Changes to the `netsh advfirewall' context.
branchcache    - Changes to the `netsh branchcache' context.
bridge         - Changes to the `netsh bridge' context.
delete         - Deletes a configuration entry from a list of entries.
dhcpclient     - Changes to the `netsh dhcpclient' context.
dnsclient      - Changes to the `netsh dnsclient' context.
dump           - Displays a configuration script.
exec           - Runs a script file.
firewall       - Changes to the `netsh firewall' context.
help           - Displays a list of commands.
http           - Changes to the `netsh http' context.
interface      - Changes to the `netsh interface' context.
ipsec          - Changes to the `netsh ipsec' context.
lan            - Changes to the `netsh lan' context.
mbn            - Changes to the `netsh mbn' context.
namespace      - Changes to the `netsh namespace' context.
netio          - Changes to the `netsh netio' context.
p2p            - Changes to the `netsh p2p' context.
ras            - Changes to the `netsh ras' context.
rpc            - Changes to the `netsh rpc' context.
set            - Updates configuration settings.
show           - Displays information.
trace          - Changes to the `netsh trace' context.
wcn            - Changes to the `netsh wcn' context.
wfp            - Changes to the `netsh wfp' context.
winhttp        - Changes to the `netsh winhttp' context.
winsock        - Changes to the `netsh winsock' context.
wlan           - Changes to the `netsh wlan' context.

The following sub-contexts are available:
 advfirewall branchcache bridge dhcpclient dnsclient firewall http interface ipsec lan mbn namespace netio p2p ras rpc trace wcn wfp winhttp winsock wlan

To view help for a command, type the command, followed by a space, and then
 type ?.
```

If you run `netsh interface ?` you will see that `delete` **is not** listed under "The following commands are available":

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh interface ?

The following commands are available:

Commands in this context:
6to4           - Changes to the `netsh interface 6to4' context.
?              - Displays a list of commands.
dump           - Displays a configuration script.
help           - Displays a list of commands.
httpstunnel    - Changes to the `netsh interface httpstunnel' context.
ipv4           - Changes to the `netsh interface ipv4' context.
ipv6           - Changes to the `netsh interface ipv6' context.
isatap         - Changes to the `netsh interface isatap' context.
portproxy      - Changes to the `netsh interface portproxy' context.
set            - Sets configuration information.
show           - Displays information.
tcp            - Changes to the `netsh interface tcp' context.
teredo         - Changes to the `netsh interface teredo' context.
udp            - Changes to the `netsh interface udp' context.

The following sub-contexts are available:
 6to4 httpstunnel ipv4 ipv6 isatap portproxy tcp teredo udp

To view help for a command, type the command, followed by a space, and then
 type ?.
```

You cannot delete an interface when in the `interface` context, but you can in the `lan` (Local Area Network), `wlan` (Wireless Local Area Network), and `mbn` (Mobile Broadband Network) contexts.  Similarly, you can uninstall a network bridge in the `bridge` context.  I think the only type of network interface you can't remove/uninstall via some `netsh` context is a loopback adapter.